# Compactness of subset of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $\ [a,b)$$\bigcup$$ (c,d]$ Compact?

$\ My Answer:$

Let S= $\ [a, b-1/n)$$\bigcup$$(c+1/n,d]$.
As $\ n$$\longrightarrow$$\infty$ S covers the given interval. But any finite subset of S doesn't cover the given set.
Therefore by definition not Compact..

Comment: But suppose $c<b\le d$? I assume we can rely on $a<b$ and $c<d$.

Comment: "but any finite subset of S doesn't cover the given set". No of course not. Finite sets do not cover infinite sets. You must be more precise. $S$ needs an index and the family $(S_n)_n$ together must be treated as a cover.

Comment: Yes... I got it......Thank You..

Answer (score 1):

For $S_n:=[a,b-\frac1{n})\cup(c+\frac1{n},d ]$ let's check whether it can happen that $[a,b)\cup(c,d]\subseteq S_n$ for some $n$ large enough.

For that we need $[b-\frac1{n},b)\subseteq(c+\frac1{n},d]$ and $(c,c+\frac1{n}]\subseteq[a,b-\frac1{n})$.

Based on $[b-\frac1{n},b)\subseteq(c+\frac1{n},d]$ we find $b\leq d$, and $b-\frac1{2n}>c+\frac1{n}$ so $b>c$.

Likewise based on $(c,c+\frac1{n}]\subseteq[a,b-\frac1{n})$ we find $c\in[a,b)$.

This together gives the extra condition $a\leq c< b\leq d$ or equivalently $[a,b)\cup(c,d]=[a,b]$.

Now note that $[a,b]$ is indeed a compact set.

If the extra condition is not satisfied then it is correct to say that no finite subcover of the covering $(S_n)_n$ exists. In that case the set is indeed not compact.